# Web service unable to connect Sharepoint site "unable to connect remote server"

Tags: c#, web-services

I have written the code as below:

```
  try
    {


        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://test.com/");
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        string strUserName = @"abc";
        string strPassword = "pwd";
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword);
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
        context.Credentials = credentials;
        context.ExecuteQuery();


        // Now, the web's properties are available and we could display 
        // web properties, such as title. 
        System.Console.WriteLine("Web Title");
        System.Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

It's working fine in the console application, but same code is not working when I am calling from a web service.

Comment: Your webservice is probably running under different credentials to your console. If it's IIS, check your app pool credentials.

Comment: if I am directly running from my asp.net application then its not working too, yes but my asp.net application is using form authentication. is that issue?

Comment: Not the forms authentication, but the account that your App pool is running under. For example, if you are running on your local machine and your company uses AD proxy auth, unless your App Pool identity also has a valid AD account to the proxy - your service will fail. Same for sharepoint access - authorization required most likely.

Comment: i agree. what would be solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Given our discussion; the problem is likely that the account that your IIS app pool is running under is not authorized to access the Sharepoint site. You need the app pool account to have access in AD in order for your code to work. You'll need to do one of the following;

Get the App pool account granted AD rights to Sharepoint. This is less likely as IIS 7 and above use "odd accounts" by default for app pools.

More likely is you'll need to change the account your app pool is running under to one that has the appropriate AD rights. In most companies I've worked for there is a "Service Account" or "Automated Account" used for this purpose.